# Cannot Use Printf!?! (while performing hashing algorithm using mhash)

Tags: c, pointers, hash, format, printf

I am using Mhash and I would like to print the length of my blocksize for debugging purposes, but I keep getting an error every time I try to compile

Any suggestions on how I can fix this error?

Here is my code:

```
#include <mhash.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// 0x12e6bc6e68c3b9506e6668db6b7224f894fab073728fc179 (TIGER192) (48)

 int main()
 {
        char password[] = "Jefe";
        int keylen = 4; 
        char data[] = "what do ya want for nothing?";
        int datalen = 28;
        MHASH td, td2;
        unsigned char *mac, *mac2;
        int i, j;

    td = mhash_hmac_init(MHASH_TIGER192, password, keylen, mhash_get_hash_pblock(MHASH_TIGER192));

        mhash(td, data, datalen); 
        mac = mhash_hmac_end(td); 

        printf("0x");
        for (i = 0; i < mhash_get_block_size(MHASH_TIGER192); i++)
    {
                printf("%.2x", mac[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");

    // int length = strlen(mac);
    // printf(length);

    // int length = 5;
    // printf(length);

        exit(0);
 }

I run the program with the following commands:
hb2@hb1:~/Desktop$ gcc -o hashexample hashexample.c -lmhash
hb2@hb1:~/Desktop$ ./hashexample
0x12e6bc6e68c3b9506e6668db6b7224f894fab073728fc179
```

And it runs successfully, but when I try to print the length of the hashed result, I get the following error!!? Any ideas on why?

```
// int length = strlen(mac);
// printf(length);

hb2@hb1:~/Desktop$ gcc -o hashexample hashexample.c -lmhash
hashexample.c: In function ‘main’:
hashexample.c:33:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘printf’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/include/stdio.h:363:12: note: expected ‘const char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘int’
hashexample.c:33:2: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
```

At first, I thought it was because I thought I was using strlen incorrectly?! But even when I try to do a simple printf of an integer, I still get an error:

```
// int length = 5;
// printf(length);

hb2@hb1:~/Desktop$ gcc -o hashexample hashexample.c -lmhash
hashexample.c: In function ‘main’:
hashexample.c:35:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘printf’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/include/stdio.h:363:12: note: expected ‘const char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘int’
hashexample.c:35:2: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: The error message is very clear, you pass an integer but [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) expects a string.

Comment: printf expects a string, and if you want, you can format it: `printf("%d",length)`

Answer (score 1):

Check the [man page for `printf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf). The first argument is a `const char *`. You're passing an `int`.

That's what the warning says too:

> > warning: passing **argument 1 of ‘printf’ makes pointer from integer** without a cast [enabled by default]

You wanted:

```
printf("%d", length);
```

You need the format string to specify that an `int` is going to be printed.